# jmespath extract a key from a list which is not json

Tags: jmespath

I am trying to extract a piece of text from a list.
The list is something like this

```py
[{'texts': [{'language': {'isoCode': 'it', 'name': 'Italian'},
    'text': 'CATETERI VENOSI CENTRALI CON ACCESSO PERIFERICO MULTILUME',
    'allLanguagesApplicable': None},
   {'language': {'isoCode': 'fr', 'name': 'French'},
    'text': 'CATHÉTERS VEINEUX CENTRAUX MULTILUMIÈRES PAR ABORD PÉRIPHÉRIQUE',
    'allLanguagesApplicable': None},
   {'language': {'isoCode': 'en', 'name': 'English'},
    'text': 'CENTRAL I.V. MULTI-LUMEN CATHETERS, PERIPHERAL ACCESS',
    'allLanguagesApplicable': None}]}]
```

I need to extract the text where `language.isoCode` is `en`.

But the JMESPath query is alluding me for some reason.

I want the output as

```json
CENTRAL I.V. MULTI-LUMEN CATHETERS, PERIPHERAL ACCESS
```

This is my try

```py
jmespath.search("[*].texts[?language.isoCode == 'en'].text[]", temp_json)
['CENTRAL I.V. MULTI-LUMEN CATHETERS, PERIPHERAL ACCESS']
```

But, I want the text only not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop the filter projection created by `[?language.isoCode == 'en']` in order to get the first element of that array.

This is exaplained in details in the chapter named [*pipe expressions*](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions) of the tutorials.

So, you query ends up being

```
[*].texts[?language.isoCode == 'en'].text[] | [0]
```

Which gives the expected:

```json
"CENTRAL I.V. MULTI-LUMEN CATHETERS, PERIPHERAL ACCESS"
```